# hostbinding angular with input variable

Tags: angular, typescript, sass

I am trying to set up the CSS styling conditionally like when the change is true, the background is red and when the change is false, the background is black. But I don't know how to let the hostbinding know this by checking the change flag. The demo code is like this:

```
 import { Component, HostBinding } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  title: string;
  change: boolean;
  @HostBinding('class.someChange') isChanged() {
    this.change = true;
    return this.change;
  }

  constructor() {
    this.title = 'Tour of Heroes';
  }
}
```

and for the HTML file is like this:

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>

<nav>
  <a routerLink = "/dashboard"> Dashboard </a>
  <a routerLink = "/heroes"> Heroes </a>
</nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-messages></app-messages>
```

The CSS file is below:

```
:host {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  background-color: rgb(0, 255, 149);
  padding: 20px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  &.someChange {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```